# Document submission after J1 visa interview

Tags: usa

After my US J1 visa interview, I was given a 221g form and I was told to submit a few documents through an online link. I have submitted the documents, but I am in the dark about the further process.

Where these documents go? To the consular officer who interviewed me or somewhere else?

How long may it take to process these documents and when should I expect to hear from the embassy again?